# Cannot Unsubscribe from LinkedIn

Tags: linkedin

I have tried endlessly to unsubscribe to LinkedIn but to no avail.  When I sign in it keeps asking for verification using the cryptic code (some you can not even read) but when I finally did read one correctly then LinkedIn said there was no account associated with my email but yet they are sending me notifications at that email address! I can not even contact their customer service as the emails I send bounce.
Any help on this would be appreciated.

Comment: Is it possible that these are spoofed or spam emails?

Comment: Does your email have a "+" sign in the address?

Answer (score 2):

1. Make sure the link in the mail is pointed to the LinkedIn website. A LOT of the LinkedIn mail are spoofed.
2. Did you try the "Unsubscribe" link at the bottom of the mail?

Comment: LinkedIn's "unsubscribe" buttons do nothing (or nothing perceptible).

Comment: The unsubscribe button does not work. It is useless. Even after turning off all email notifications still they send marketing emails. They do not respect user's privacy.